# Understanding remote shared objects in Flex and ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have 2 questions about remote shared objects in Flex/ActionScript3:

1) If I connect to a remote shared objects, but do not handle the SYNC event, will the shared object still receive data from the server? ie. will the server still broadcast data to this client ? This is what I expect, but please let me know

2) Is the entire object state send each time the SYNC event is fired, or is it only the changes to the object state? I believe it is only the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes. If you are connected to server you will receive sync event no matter if you have listener for it

2) Only changes. There is changeList property in SyncEvent that has an array of object that are changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every time you make a connection with FMS onSync Event is going to be called..
2. syncEvent is only called when you make any change in your shared object array..and never else.